# Magento 2 : how to include custom image in email template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, media-images

I have made some email templates, i am not much sure **where i can add image files & use it in email templates** ?

Is their is possible way to get it ?

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Thankyou

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can upload images at the **module** level or **theme** level inside the `web/images` folder and use the below code inside the email template for getting these images.

```
<img src="{{view url='Package_Modulename/images/customimg.png'}}" height="100" width="100" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />
```

Comment: I have added image file in app/code/Mod/sales/view/frontend/web/images/order_pickup.png

Comment: Replace "Package_Modulename" with your module name and also replace "customimg.png" with "order_pickup.png".

Comment: Thanks, is this the ideal way to add images ?
As i will use it in email templates ?

Comment: Your module name should be "Mod_Sales"

Comment: Yes it is the best way to add images to email templates.

Comment: Do i need to execute static content ?

Comment: No need to execute the deploy command if your website in developer mode otherwise you can try to execute the deploy command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an image from media folder, you can use as below:

```
<img src="{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/MyImage.jpg&quot;}}" alt="{{trans 'My Image'}}" />
```